# curl failed when downloading data from sumo logic

Tags: api, ssl, curl, download, sumologic

I am trying to use api to download data. My code is:

```
curl -u "accessID***:accessKey***" -X GET https://api.au.sumologic.com/api/v1/collectors?limit=2   (just follow the example from https://help.sumologic.com/APIs/Search-Job-API/About-the-Search-Job-API). But I have got the error:
```

> Curl:(60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it. ...

Image:

[image]

I tried to read the info from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html. But this is my first time to use api and curl. I really cannot understand how to fix this problem .

I run this code on a Windows server. I download the curl from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html. The version is

> Windows 64 bit    7.61.1  binary  the curl project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html` instead `https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html` you will avoid the SSL requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you please explain how to "use" this webpage? Really do not know about this.

Comment: First get your `accessId` and `accessKey`. Then once you got it, encode it in `base64` all together like this: `echo -n "your-accessId:your-accessKey" | base64`. It will give you something like `QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1`. Now you can authenticate like that `curl -H "Authorization: Basic <encoded string like QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1>" -X GET https://api.YOUR_DEPLOYMENT.sumologi...ectors?limit=2`

Comment: Thanks very much. Really help me a lot

Comment: My pleasure anytime!